# Code invoked too many times

Tags: google-sheets, google-apps-script, formulas, google-sheets-custom-function

My goal is pretty simple: take the value in column U and check if it's within particular ranges. If it's 1–100, put a 1 in column A. If it's 101–200, put a 2 in column A. The problem is, I have almost 2000 rows of numbers in column U. Putting `=function(U2)` in each cell in column A results in a

> Script invoked too many times per second

error, and adding `Utilities.sleep(500)` at the end doesn't help either. Here's my code so far. Please excuse the ugliness, as I'm a very beginner programmer.

```
function assignBoxNumber(sgNumber) {
  if(sgNumber>=1 && sgNumber<=71) {
    return "1"
  }
  if(sgNumber==72) {
    return "1 and 2"
  }
  if(sgNumber>=73 && sgNumber<=125) {
    return "2"
  }
  if(sgNumber==126) {
    return "2 and 3"
  }
  if(sgNumber>=127 && sgNumber<=202) {
    return "3"
  }
  if(sgNumber>=207 && sgNumber<=269) {
    return "4"
  }
  if(sgNumber>=270 && sgNumber<=333) {
    return "5"
  }
  if(sgNumber>=334 && sgNumber<=433) {
    return "6"
  }
  if(sgNumber>=434 && sgNumber<=497) {
    return "7"
  }
  if(sgNumber>=498 && sgNumber<=560) {
    return "8"
  }
  if(sgNumber>=561 && sgNumber<=627) {
    return "9"
  }
  if(sgNumber>=628 && sgNumber<=691) {
    return "10"
  }
  if(sgNumber>=692 && sgNumber<=791) {
    return "11"
  }
  if(sgNumber>=792 && sgNumber<=872) {
    return "12"
  }
  if(sgNumber>=874 && sgNumber<=955) {
    return "13"
  }
  if(sgNumber>=956 && sgNumber<=1019) {
    return "14"
  }
  else {
    return "Error: No box location!"
  }
  Utilities.sleep(500)
}
```

Comment: `If i t's 1-100, put a 1 in column A.` What about 72-100? And yeah the code is extremely messy.

Comment: The 1-100 is meant as an example. My ranges are from 1-71, 72, 73-125, etc. as shown in my if statements.

Comment: Have a look at a similar question: http://webapps.stackexchange.com/a/60298/29140

Answer (score 3):

You may not need a script for this as a formula of the kind:

```
=iferror(vlookup(U1,D$1:E$20,2),"Error: No box location!")
```

copied down to suit may serve where D1:E20 is a table of the kind:

[image: WA66026 example]

This could be in the same sheet but seems sensible to hold such 'reference' data in a separate sheet (in which case the formula above would require the addition of a sheet reference).

If double-clicking works for coping down the speed is about the same as for a user defined function and may even be faster, though neither should take more than about 10 seconds for 2000 rows.

Comment: That requires an additional sheet plus many `VLOOKUP` formulae will make it slow.

Comment: Jacob, I would always go for native functions, rather than custom, in the interest of performance. Even better would be applying as an array formula. Regarding the additional sheet - the lookup data has to go somewhere! (whether in separate cells, or hardcoded into the formula, or in Google Apps Script). Array formula would be something like: `=ArrayFormula(IF(LEN(U:U),IFERROR(VLOOKUP(U:U,D1:E20,2),"Error: No box location!"),))`

Comment: @Adaml I agree. In this case, the OP made an effort to make something work in GAS. I and another poster made suggestions about how to improve the code.

Comment: @JacobJanTuinstra yes I think the GAS answers are totally appropriate, given the question. I guess my comment was directed more towards your comment above it, rather than your answer. In that I would generally recommend native functions (used optimally) rather than custom functions in the interest of performance. But that is indeed a generalisation - in some cases, just deleting blank rows in a sheet will give the best performance increase of all!

Answer (score 1):

I would go about doing it like so.

### Code

```
function myValues(range) {
  var output = [];
  for(var i = 0, iLen = range.length; i < iLen; i++) {
    output.push(checkValue(range[i][0]));
  }  
  return output;
}

function checkValue(value) {
  var check;
  if(value >= 1 && value <= 71) {
    check = 1;
  } else if (value == 72) {
    check = '1 and 2';
  } else if (value >= 73 && value <= 125) {
    check = 2;
  } else if (value == 126) {
    check = '2 and 3';
  } else {
    check = 'Error: No box location!';
  }
  return check.toString();
}
```

### Note

Make sure to add the rest of the criteria yourself !!

### Example

I've created an example file for you: **[code invoked too many times](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1KW96ugXTpM8b5UsU_L7jUZtqbOqGEZcQPzNfW3f8Rug/edit?usp=sharing)**

Answer (score 0):

Google's help center [says](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/services/quotas):

> *Script invoked too many times per second for this Google user account.* This indicates that the script began executing too many times in a short period. It most commonly occurs for custom functions that are called repeatedly in a single spreadsheet. To avoid this error, code your custom functions so that they only **need to be called once per range of data**, as explained in the guide to custom functions.

I'm assuming this is because calling a custom function takes a lot of memory (going through the existing functions [possibly in Google's servers] to see if it's there, then turning back to execute it). You need to make it so that it will be only called *once* instead of 2000 times. The fact that you added `sleep()` did nothing because it's unreachable (you are always `return`ing before you get to that statement), but, even if it wasn't, it would only make it worse because it doesn't sleep between invocations, but rather *after each* invocation.

Your code is a little funny, and I was especially amused at the `else` clause at the end. I couldn't find a pattern for your ranges so I just stored all the upper bounds and their respective outputs in two arrays. In addition, for the code to only be invoked once, I made it so that you have to choose what range you want and it returns an array (each element is outputted on a different row). Check it out:

```
function assignBoxNumber(range){
  var maxes = [1, 72, 73, 126, 127, 203, 207, 270, 334, 434, 498, 561, 628, 692, 792, 873, 874, 956, 1020];
  var vals = ["", "1", "1 and 2", "2", "2 and 3", "3", "", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9", "10", "11", "12", "", "13", "14"];
  //if (maxes.length != vals.length) {return "you fucked up"; }
  var length = range.length, output = new Array(length);
  var i, obj, key;
  for (var row = 0; row < length; row++)
  {
    obj = range[row][0];
    key = "";
    for (i = 0; i < maxes.length; i++)
    {
      if (obj < maxes[i]){ key = vals[i]; break;}
    }
    output[row] = (key == "") ? "Error: No box location!" : key;
  }
  return output;
};
```

Note that the parameter is a **range**. Meaning that it will be in the format of `<cell1>:<cell2>`, `U1:U20` for instance, but it's **NOT** a string. The first number is the first cell (in the example `U1`), the second is the last cell (`U20`). You can also select the region you want to help you get the range:

[image]

But obviously for 2k+ rows you want to write it in. So call the function like `=assignBoxNumber(<first cell>:<last cell>)`.

I tested it on 1,021 rows and it worked perfectly. I understand why there was a problem before - it takes some time to actually find the custom function. There shouldn't be a problem now that there's only 1 call to the custom function.

**UPDATE:** Fixed the arrays and now the output is [completely identical to that of your messy method](http://ideone.com/z8R0EV).